# Migrated question still visible in Open Data

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

Why a migrated question is still visible to Open Data stack exchange.

For instance this question [(link)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/feature-based-malware-detection-using-weka) is on the question list of open data, but if I click on it, I moved to another stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migrated question on the originating site is [deleted after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082).  The stub kept for two reasons:

1. Migrations can be reversed if the question is closed on the destination site.
2. It can be confusing to see a question migration when the original is missing.  Remember that people on the destination site often won't be able to see deleted questions on the target site.